# su not asking for password

Tags: root, password, su

My `su` does not ask for password. When I run `su` it simply logs me in to `root`. I tried `su - root` then it asks for password. Now, because of this `kdesu` runs applications with root rights without password. I tried replacing `su` with the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
/root/./su - root 
exit
```

I moved my su into `/root`.

Now `kdesu` asks for a password but hangs as soon as I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing the password.

I'm using Arch Linux.

Comment: Have you edited `/etc/pam.d/su` or any of the other authentication configs?

Comment: @jasonwryan - thanks man i completely forgot about `/etc/pam.d/su` found the problem and fixed it!

Answer (score 5):

As `man su` notes, `/etc/pam.d/su` is the default PAM configuration file for `su`. One of the options is to grant implicit elevated privileges for anyone in the `wheel` group:

```
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
auth        sufficient  pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
```

With this line uncommented, when you issue `su` without any arguments, `su` defaults to running an interactive shell as root and, if your user is in the `wheel` group, *without a password prompt*.